# How to make an options menu for a PopupWindow?

Tags: java, android

My app has an options menu that is available in almost all Activities, which was created by implementing onCreateOptionsMenu(). But in one Activity there is a PopupWindow, and when this PopupWindow has focus (required for proper functioning) tapping the menu button does not bring up the options menu.

PopupWindows do not have an onCreateOptionsMenu() function. Is there some other way to add an options menu to a PopupWindow?

Alternatively, is there a way to get the options menu from the Activity behind it to show up when the user taps the menu button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by intercepting the menu key and calling openOptionsMenu() on the activity. Here is the key listener:

```
OnKeyListener mMenuKeyListener = new OnKeyListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onKey(View view, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if(keyCode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU) {
            activity.openOptionsMenu();
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
};
```

I think you have to add this key listener to every view in the PopupWindow to get it to work, so I wrote a function to do that:

```
public void setupMenuKeyListenerRecursive(View v) {
    if (v != null) {
        try {
            ViewGroup viewGroup = (ViewGroup)v;
            int childCount = viewGroup.getChildCount();
            for (int index = 0; index < childCount; index++) {
                View child = viewGroup.getChildAt(index);
                setupMenuKeyListenerRecursive(child);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        v.setOnKeyListener(mMenuKeyListener);
    }
}
```